# h3 takes full width

Tags: html, css

I would like to make below image. However, I could not combine both `display:inline` and `display: block` together. If I use `display: block,` everything goes on the same line. On the other hand, if I use `display block`, every element goes to new line. 
Here is my code

HTML

```
<ul>
            <li class="icon">
                    <img src="images/how/post.png" alt="post">
                <h4>1. Post</h4>
            </li>
            <li class="icon">
                <img src="images/how/wait.png" alt="wait">
                <h4>2. Wait</h4>
            </li>
            <li class="icon">
                <img src="images/how/select.png" alt="select">
                <h4>3. Select</h4>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

CSS

```
ul{
        list-style: none;
        li{
            display: inline;
            h4{
                display:inline;
            }
        }
        img{
            width: 6rem;
        }
    }
```

Please see an image here of what I would like it to be.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1W7dq.png)

Comment: In your .scss/less file the img tag should be listed inside the li.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this way `display:inline-block` and `display:block`

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul li h4 {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
ul img {
  width: 6rem;
}

img {
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
            <li class="icon">
                    <img src="https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2018/new-years-eve-2018-4995722058399744.2-law.gif" alt="post">
                <h4>1. Post</h4>
            </li>
            <li class="icon">
                <img src="https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2018/new-years-eve-2018-4995722058399744.2-law.gif" alt="wait">
                <h4>2. Wait</h4>
            </li>
            <li class="icon">
                <img src="https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2018/new-years-eve-2018-4995722058399744.2-law.gif" alt="select">
                <h4>3. Select</h4>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you remove all the features that HTML list gives, you probably don't need a list. I suggest using divs instead. Set your container with

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
```

to get the layout you want.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.icon {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-basis: 200px;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

img {
  width: 6rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="icon">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="post" />
    <h4>1. Post</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="icon">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="wait" />
    <h4>2. Wait</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="icon">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="select" />
    <h4>3. Select</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

HTML:

```
<ul>
            <li class="icon">
                    <img src="images/how/post.png" alt="post">
                <h4>1. Post</h4>
            </li>
            <li class="icon">
                <img src="images/how/wait.png" alt="wait">
                <h4>2. Wait</h4>
            </li>
            <li class="icon">
                <img src="images/how/select.png" alt="select">
                <h4>3. Select</h4>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

SCSS:

```
ul{
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    li{
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 33.33%;
        text-align: center;
        h4{
            display:inline-block;
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
    img{
        width: 6rem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**pls try this code**

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        ul {
            list-style: none;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
        ul li{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        ul li h4 {
            display: inline;
        }
        ul li img {
            width: 6rem;
        }
    </style>

</head>    

<body>
    <ul>
        <li class="icon">
                <img src="images/how/post.png" alt="post">
            <h4>1. Post</h4>
        </li>
        <li class="icon">
            <img src="images/how/wait.png" alt="wait">
            <h4>2. Wait</h4>
        </li>
        <li class="icon">
            <img src="images/how/select.png" alt="select">
            <h4>3. Select</h4>
        </li>
    </ul> 
</body>
</html>
```